# The best way to act with a model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Task model:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    taken = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    client = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', related_name='tasks_given')
    executor = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', related_name='tasks_received')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Task #'+str(self.id)
```

and I have to handle its creation, validation, cancelling etc.
What's the best way to do it? Is it better to have one (for all cases) or few (for each case) functions in `views.py`? Is it better to have one template with a lot of `{% if %}` or is it better to have a few? *Any* other hints will be appreciated =)

Comment: The main question, do I need to divide model's actions to a few functions instead of one with a lot of conditions. The same question about templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For actions, you'd better extend class-based generic views, they are quite modular, have most of the functionality already baked in and sensible defaults for template names etc.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#detail-views

They are based on mixin composition, so for each piece or step of functionality there is a very specific method you have to override. Once you get it it is very simple.

For templates, use the `extends` and `include` tags and avoid repeated code. Try to use most automatically generated code as you can.

Comment: thank you, i'll learn more about generic views

Answer (score 0):

You can use the django-admin site, as illustrated in [chapter 2 of the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/).

Comment: iknow about django-admin, i mean all this actions are performed by user

Comment: @mindmaster, give the user access to the `django-admin`?  that's what it is meant for.

Comment: users that don't have admin rights have to be able to manage tasks too

Comment: Aye, give them permission to only touch the Task model.  [ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/)

Comment: @rm Except that you give someone permission to manage their tasks, that the can manage ALL the tasks, not only theirs

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "best way to act," but if you want to handle the object creation and validation, you can write extra methods in your model.

```
class Task(Models.model):
    ...
    ## fields
    ...

    ## Example of a method on the model
    def validate(self):
        ## validate the model here
```

I think you want to minimize the validation code in the view. It would be nice if from your view, you can validate like:

```
new_task.validate()
```

instead of having to write the validation in every view you want to use the Task model.

Comment: i mean is it better to write a lot of if's in one function to handle different situations (creating, viewing etc) or it's better to make few functions instead of one

Comment: I think it's better to have several functions instead of one. I think you would have one function per type of functionality you want. That means one for creating, and another one for validating.

Comment: and what about template? is it better to have one for creating/viewing/listing or several templates will be better?

Comment: I don't know more about the overall setup of your project, but if you think creating/viewing/listing are reusable components, they should be their own template that you can include or extend.